# Override webpage doctype in my browser?

Tags: browser, html, webpage, rendering

My CIS class' webpages seem to be using the shorthand HTML4 Doctype (as in, not with the full W3C URL) and improperly formed HTML. I'm having trouble seeing the pages although several professors seems to see it just fine. Is there a way to force my browser to render more leniently?

I have access to Safari on Mac OS X Lion, IE on Windows 7, and Chrome and Firefox on either Mac or Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's seems like your professors may be using outdated browsers. For Windows, you can try older versions of Firefox  and Google Chrome using the portable editions provided by [PortableApps.com](http://portableapps.com/). These packages are open source and hosted on [SourceForge.net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/portableapps/).

- [Firefox Portable](http://sourceforge.net/projects/portableapps/files/Mozilla%20Firefox,%20Portable%20Ed./)
- [Google Chrome Portable](http://sourceforge.net/projects/portableapps/files/Google%20Chrome%20Portable/)

If it is the CSS that is causing problems, you can disable CSS under `View > Page Style > No Style` in Firefox.