# Installer for previous versions of Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, installer, version

I am lost in where to find previous version installer downloads for Google Chrome. I checked FileHippo but theirs are BETA versions. I am looking for stable previous versions. Currently, my Google Chrome is in **17.0.963.46 m**.

Where can I find them?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Which operating system? If you are using Windows, see my answer here: http://superuser.com/a/385481/100787

Answer (score 0):

Softpedia has [numerous Chrome releases](http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/Google-Chrome-Download-108166.html).

Comment: That link just points to the latest version.